# É possível deixar parte de uma imagem transparent? CSS

Tags: css, imagem

Possuo isto: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] e isto [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso de algo como isto: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

pensei em colocar uma div dentro da outra, a div pai contendo uma imagem inteira e a div filho contendo outra imagem, só que a div filho exibindo apenas metade da imagem, se houver uma maneira de deixar metade da imagem transparent já resolve

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o já tentou fazer na forma dum [mcve].

Comment: Da para fazer isso de várias formas, tem que ver qual eh a melhor para a sua situação, então indico vc editar a sua pergunta e incluir o que vc já tentou de código etc.